# Order by first non-null result that comes from two different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, sql-order-by

I want to browse through all values of two columns in a table:

- if the value in column 1 is not null, select it, otherwise select the value in column 2 instead.
- then sort the final result in alphabetical ascending order, wherever column its values came from.

I tried the following query but it doesn't work and I'm not even sure it is supposed to do what I want to do.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ), 
         col1 DESC, 
         col2 DESC)
```

Besides the fact that it doesn't work (nothing outputted), it seems to sort the values of each column separately while I want to sort the final set of values retrieved, regardless of the column they are from.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fix it with the `CASE` expression, it'd look like the following:

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL 
            THEN col1 
            ELSE col2 
       END AS col
FROM table 
ORDER BY col
```

Although a nice option is using the `COALESCE` function. It returns the first non-null value in the list of arguments.

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(col1, col2) AS col
FROM table 
ORDER BY col
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. Both queries are helpful. The fact that you used a "col" for "grouping" the values and sort on that "col" is what I wanted without knowing how to do. And your second query is elegant and less verbose. Nice.